# Upload a paid app after I already uploaded a free one?

Tags: android

I had appsmakerstore help me upload my app after I used their software.  When it was time to publish my app,  appsmakerstore never asked me if I wanted to price it and just uploaded it under free apps.  Now google play is telling me after it has been set to fee then I can't price it.  They said I have to upload a new apk with a new name and I'm not sure what to do.  Any advise  please?  I don't want anyone uploading my app for free.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing you could do is unpublish that free app and and reload your priced app under a different name like they said. Google will not allow you to change a free app to a paid version, this is so that you won't confuse the consumer in thinking that the app has a huge paid user base.

Comment: Thank you Broody,  when they say rename it, do they mean the app name or the apk name?

Comment: I don't think the Android Market cares about application name or the actual filename of the .apk file.  I think it's the package name in AndroidManifest.xml that you need to change.  This means that you get to keep the name of the application. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.)

Comment: Yeah it's the package name. You'll need to refactor your code, eclipse can do this easily.

Comment: @EdwardFalk You're right. But this question should be closed. A coder/ programmer is supposed to know how to publish an app, and how to refactor package name. The question is off-topic.

Comment: I dunno; I think any reasonable programmer would want to know if it was possible to do what OP wanted to do.  Seems like a fair question to me.  I saw that because I had the same problem a couple years ago.